# Identify parts number - two sides and top of a square (one solid piece)

Tags: part-identification, vintage

Please help me identify this part.
It has nothing on it except "LEGO".
Thanks.

[image: two sides and top of a square]

Answer (score 6):

This is part # 821

[Garage Door Frame](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=821#T=C)

[image]